# Handwrite or generate typescript .d.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Typescript lets you use `"declaration": true"` in tsconfig to generate the d.ts files based on existing Typescript code. They are not as concise as if I wrote it myself, but I'm wondering if there is a reason to not rely on these as they seem somewhat accurate.

Edit: We are creating a library in Typescript.

Comment: The answer to this question is pretty subjective. Personally I wouldn't waste my time creating something that can be generated automatically. Hand written declaration files should be used when integrating an existing javascript library with typescript.

Comment: Thank you @JakeHolzinger, I thought the same too. Why manually do something that can be automated. We are creating a library in TS, and are wondering if we should write the declarations ourselves or just use autogenerated declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should let TypeScript build declaration files for you when creating a library. Hand-writing `*.d.ts` files is good when you have a JavaScript library, but you want to describe its behavior with types.

There are exceptions — for example, you may want to clean the generated files by removing unwanted comments. One might argue that can be solved by marking them as `@internal` though.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!